# Resources that give intuition/geometric visualization for KKT conditions, lagrangian and dual problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I started studying convex optimization for Machine Learning and I'm reading stuff about KKT conditions, lagrangians, dual functions and dual problems etc., but I still don't understand how they actually work, or what is exactly happening. It feels like I only know the algorithms to work out problems. Any reference resources that build on the geometrical/visual/textual intuition for the mentioned topics would be really helpful. I want to get a solid feel for it, and not just remain limited to memorizing conditions/facts.

P.S: Anything that builds up from scratch would be better.

Comment: There's [this MOOC](https://www.edx.org/course/convex-optimization).

Answer (score 1):

"Theory of Convex Optimisation" by Dimitri P. Bertsekas does exactly what you're asking for. It focuses on duality through a very intuitive and visual manner, in contrast with some of the more classical treatment of the topics.

The book is available free here:
http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Convex_Theory_Entire_Book.pdf

Comment: Hopefully it is better than boyd, because I found boyd's book pretty clumsy and not visual enough.